# Drop Down Menu in Django displaying as text field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've followed the process laid out on the Django ModelForm's documentation, as well as a couple of tutorials. My field displays as a standard text-entry, rather than a drop down. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

forms.py

```
from .models import Authority  # change to rating!!!
from django import forms

class AuthorityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Authority
        fields = ('authority_name',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Authority
from .forms import AuthorityForm

# Create your views here.
class HomeCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Authority
    form_class = AuthorityForm
    template_name = 'home.html'
    success_url = 'home.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Authority(models.Model):
    authority_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    authority_url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.authority_name

class Rating(models.Model):
    authority_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    ratings = models.CharField(max_length = 20000)
    # Could this be reduced if remove the trailing letters of non-int values?
    # Perhaps all values could be one-hot encoded
```

home.html

```
  <h2>Choose Authority:</h2>
  <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: What field do you want as a drop down? In the only form you show here, `authority_name` is a `CharField`. It would only be a drop down if it had [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices). An alternative is to have a `ForeignKey`, and then you'll have a drop down with all the related objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to make authority_name the drop down, with the list being populated by all the authority_name entries in my model.

Comment: My aim is to direct the user to a page with certain data, dependent on their chosen authority. The authority model will hold the data, once populated. Is it possible to assign the choices parameter to be a list of the authority names?

Comment: `choices` is usually static, as the documentation I linked to before says: "if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey". I'm not sure I understand your data model, but from what you're saying, you need to create a model that will hold the authority names, where `name` is a `CharField` and then in the model where you want to use the authority names you create a `ForeignKey` to the model that has the authority names.

Comment: Thank you,  that makes absolute sense. Will update after I have attempted.

Comment: For instance, in the models you show, `Rating` should have something like `authority = models.ForeignKey('Authority')`, instead of the `CharField`. Then if you create a `RatingForm`, `authority` will be a drop down.

Comment: I have updated the rest, still having trouble assigning the choices variable, though. authority_name = models.ForeignKey('Authority', on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=(Authority.authority_name)) is spitting out the error 'deferred attribute does not support indexing'

Comment: You don't set `choices` on a `ForeignKey`, it will automatically pick them up from the objects of the related model.

Comment: Incredible! I was over-complicating it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Cool, no problem :)